# Why does my sprite go to the wrong co-ordinates after the first move?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Here is my movement method:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint location_ = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    NSLog(@"Click Position = (%f,%f)",location_.x,location_.y);

    float moveSpeed = 40.0;
    float moveDist = sqrt(pow(abs(location_.x - sprite.position.x),2) + pow(abs(location_.y - sprite.position.y),2));
    float moveTime = (moveDist / moveSpeed);

    [sprite runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveTime position:location_]];
}
```

And here's my init method.

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        // create and initialize a Label

        [self scheduleUpdate];  // available since v0.99.3
        [self schedule: @selector(update:) interval:0.5];

        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"testBG.png"];
        bg.position = ccp(  size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
        [self addChild: bg];

        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"testSprite.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(  size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
        [self addChild: sprite];

        [self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:sprite]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My window follows the sprite around, but like I said, the sprite will go to a different point than touched after the first touch. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

edit: I'm thinking that it may have to do with the co-ordinate system itself, or maybe it's to do with

`[touches anyObject];`? My searches have turned up little.

edit2: I've found that if I return my sprite back to the middle of the bg sprite again, it'll behave normally again from there, until it's too far off.

Comment: So strange, and one thing more you can use "ccpDistance" to find distance between two points available in cocos2D :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with `[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:sprite]];`.

`self`is your **Scene** that you don't want to move around.

The pattern for doing this would be to add a `CCNode`that you would call a your `_contentNode`to your `scene`and add everything you would like to move as a child.

Then you would call `[_contentNode runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:sprite]];`

Answer (score 0):

IN this I'll suggest you a simple thing... Before adding a new action, stop the previous action on the sprite...

In your ccTouchesBegan method

```
[sprite stopAllActions];

[sprite runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveTime position:location_]];
```

I think this will help as you sprite will stop once you touch..

In current case its undergoing an action.. Suppose its duration is 2 sec. and on next touch you run action of 1 sec. Then it will go to wrong point as previous action is still not completed.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: This didn't work. I always would wait until the first movement was completed before I would touch again anyways.